# How to calculate and compensate group delay caused by channel and how to define group delay to wideband signal?

Tags: group-delay, channel, motion-compensation

Suppose a wideband signal is sent and received by a RX. If different frequency components travel in different speed then there exists group delay in the signal, right? Not consider the multipath effect causing signal spread. Is there any algorithm that can calculate and compensate the group delay caused by channel? If the group delay caused by devices in TX end is also not known, can it calculate and compensate in RX end? Suppose I have a wideband signal, OFDM, for example, is its group delay the average delay time for every frequency components within the wideband frequency range?

Comment: One word: interleave.

Answer (score 0):

The channel frequency response (including amplitude, and phase) can be estimated and compensated using channel estimation/equalization algorithms such as training sequence-based least squares (LS) and LMS estimators.Once you estimate the channel response, you convolve the received signal with the inverse of the estimated channel response. This will cancel the effect of the transmission channel and compensate the channel induced group delay

Comment: Thank you. Do you know how to compensate the group delay induced by the filters in the TX end.

Comment: What modulation format is used? What is the transmission system? OFDM? QAM? We need more details

Comment: I think it’s OFDM. Is there any algorithm to compensate group delay for OFDM modulation?

Comment: Yes, just search for OFDM channel estimation and equalization. There are plenty of matlab codes available on the internet for this